# Why is this not a counter-example to ∂∂S = ø?

Tags: general-topology

I know that the boundary of the boundary of a set ($\partial\partial S$) is always supposed to be empty, but I have an example where I don't see why this holds, and I would appreciate it if you could point out why it's wrong:

Take as our set $S$ the open ball $B_2$ unioned with the half-sphere $S_1 \cap [-1, 1] \times [-1, 0]$. So basically it's a unit ball closed on its bottom half and open on its top half.

Then isn't it true that:

$\partial S = S_1 \cap [-1, 1] \times [-1, 0]$

$\partial\partial S = \{-1,0\} \cup \{1,0\} \neq \emptyset$

Obviously there's some flaw in my thinking here, so I appreciate you all pointing out what it is.

Comment: I denote $Int(A)$ the interior of a set $A$. Since $Int(\partial S)=\emptyset$, you have for example that $B(-1,\varepsilon )\cap Int(\partial S)=\varnothing $ for all $\varepsilon >0$. Therefore $-1\notin \partial \partial S$.

Comment: $\partial S=S_1$ not the lower half-sphere only.

Comment: If $C$ is the Cantor set in $\Bbb R$, $\partial S=C$ and $\partial \partial S=C$ again.. so the first sentence is already wrong.

Comment: Oh I see, so this boundary-of-a-boundary property only applies to manifolds then, not sets in general?

Comment: But my set $S$ is a manifold right, so it should hold here? And the reason it seemed not to is because the boundary is really all of $S_1$ as @Chrystomath said?

Comment: There are (at least) two different meanings of the word “boundary”; see the introduction here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology). And also this section further down on the same page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)#Boundary_of_a_boundary

Comment: @Lundmark yes but it says on that page that all of those listed definitions are equivalent?